# Not getting appium/android supportive methods for driver

Tags: appium

I am not able to use methods like isLocked(),closeApp(),isinstall()
I am not getting these options for ctrl + space after 'driver.'
Am I missing some library?
Please let me if more info required

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
```

Comment: Add code snippets from your driver setup function

Comment: David I have added my driver setup function.Have a look thank you